# Disable trackpoint acceleration in Gnome 3 on Wayland

Tags: debian, gnome3, wayland, libinput

I am using Debian 11 (testing) and Gnome 3. I was able to disable mouse pointer acceleration using gnome tweaks but there is still annoying acceleration when using a trackpoint. Looking through Gnome 3 and [Wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/pointer-acceleration.html) documentation I was not able to find an option to disable it. The laptop is a Lenovo T430s.

Is there any way to disable the trackpoint acceleration?

Comment: Have you looked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43430/trackpoint-hard-to-control-after-debian-update

Comment: @kasa This looks like a Xorg solution but I am using Wayland.

Comment: I think you may want to create a feature request to Gnome on exposing this setting.

Comment: @problemofficer Yes you are Wayland. I didn't want to repeat what has written there. I am archlinux, I know there is some dependency that connected with graphical environment, look at the XWayland. If you look at xorg-xwayland you will find that wayland is depend.

Comment: I have just checked my L420 (Archlinux) with #libinput list-devices , my Trackpoint Accel profile is flat *adaptive, it is working file with me.

Comment: I have found out that [libinput shows only the default options](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/tools.html#libinput-list-devices) and not what is currently configured by Wayland.